How can I have a prefix for Magit-Blame-Read-Only minor mode?
I find that its keys interferes with org-mode speed keys
Can I have a prefix somehow?

Untested: I would do
(setq magit-blame-read-only-mode-submap magit-blame-read-only-mode-map)
(setq magit-blame-read-only-mode-map (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
                                       (define-key map (kbd "<some-prefix>")
                                                   magit-blame-read-only-mode-submap)
                                       map))

and I would do that in some org-mode hook, with local values of the two symbols above (maybe using setq-local instead of setq?), so they don't interfere with magit-blame in other modes.
As mentioned, completely untested (not even checked for parens), so caveat emptor: try it (and debug it if necessary - it probably will be necessary) in a throwaway Emacs session only, before trusting it on your precious Emacs session.
